# Is there a index.html template page in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I started using NextJS today, porting a ReactJS website to it. It seems to be a great framework, but I am missing one thing.

In pure ReactJS (no NextJS framework) there is a `public/index.html` page which serves as a template where all ReactJS components are mounted. In certain situations, when I need to add a certain script in all my pages, I just edit `public/index.html` and add the script to its `<head></head>` section.

A good example is my FontAwesome kit, which I add to all my ReactJS pages by inserting

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9999999999.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

to `<head></head>` section of `public/index.html`.

I searched the basic structure of a NextJS project and found no equivalent file.

**How can I do the same using NextJS?**

Comment: Maybe use the Head component from the next/head package to add scripts and other resources to the <head> element

Comment: @Be-WiseIndependent Do I have to add this to all my pages, one by one? Because in ReactJS I may add it only to the template page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have _document.tsx file (generate one under pages folder if you do not have it yet). You can see its content on each page.

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document

Between Head tags you can use NextJs Script component to run your scripts

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script

Answer (score 1):

In the index.tsx or index.js file, you will find you are able to use `<Head></Head>` which serves the same purpose.

Comment: Great, but then I need to add this to all my pages, one by one, right? Not the same as in ReactJS, where I could to this in a single point and it would serve all my pages.